# Как импортировать kernel32.dll?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить информацию о памяти, импортируя kernel32.dll, но при компиляции возникает исключение:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [cs630327.vk.me](http://cs630327.vk.me/v630327952/13994/GIBv0lQkO-Y.jpg))</sub>

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadInfo();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] //ф-ция вызова просмотра памяти
public static extern IntPtr GlobalAlloc(int con, int size); //для выделения памяти

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] // для освобждения
public static extern int GlobalFree(IntPtr start);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatus(ref MEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer);

public struct MEMORYSTATUS
{
    public UInt32 dwLenght; //размер структуры, в байтах
    public UInt32 dwMemoryLoad;
    public UInt32 dwTotalphys;
    public UInt32 dwAvailPhys;
    public UInt32 dwTotalPageFile;
    public UInt32 dwAvailPageFile;
    public UInt32 dwTotalVirtual;
}

public void LoadInfo()
{
    MEMORYSTATUS menStat = new MEMORYSTATUS();
    GlobalMemoryStatus(ref menStat);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(menStat.dwMemoryLoad.ToString());
}
```

Исключение `System.AccessViolationException`:

> Попытка чтения или записи в защищённую память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

Comment: Исключение у вас происходит во время выполнения. Опубликуйте лучше его текст прямо в вопросе, другие смогут обратиться в гугл с его текстом.

Comment: если надо получить информацию о ram, то можно использовать performance counter, например: `var c = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true); var v = c.NextValue();` -- метод можно вызывать по таймеру. чтобы получить список разных счетчиков см. PerformanceCounterCategory

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в имени функции. Правильно `GlobalMemoryStatus`. Именно это вам и говорит сообщение об ошибке в исключении: в kernel32.dll не нашлось имя `GlobalMemorystatus` в таблице экспорта.

---

Для того, чтобы определять сигнатуры для P/Invoke, имеет смысл подсмотреть на [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/). В частности, для вашего случая там [рекомендуется следующая сигнатура](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GlobalMemoryStatus.html):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatus(ref MEMORYSTATUS lpBuffer);
```

Comment: Теперь такая ошибка) как быть? http://cs630327.vk.me/v630327952/139ca/xBAnT2dGhyU.jpg

Comment: @inkorpus: А можно новый код и текст исключения в текстовом виде?

Comment: внёс изменения в мой код выше

Comment: @inkorpus: Судя по всему, вам нужно ещё исправить определение `MEMORYSTATUS`: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MEMORYSTATUS.html

Comment: я изменил имя переменных на MEMORYSTATUSs и GlobalMemoryStatuss и возникла старая ошибка, показанная на скриншоте, в самом посту

Comment: @inkorpus: `GlobalMemoryStatuss` — это не переменная, это имя функции. Переименуйте её назад, как правильно.

Comment: ну значит не работают Ваши советы тогда